# Oneliner command to use kill given tcp port number instead of PID?

Tags: bash, scripts, command-line, kill

I often do e.g.

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :8088
```

view the output

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN      11189/java
```

and then

```
sudo kill -kill 11189
```

I'd like to have a more convenient command exactly like `killatport 8088` that uses the tcp port number as a variable and that I can make as an alias to a pipeline that does what I want, but how do I get the PID from the output and pipe it to the kill command? I suppose I might be able to use awk to get the PID from the output from netstat, but how do I safeguard and make an exact port match so that the input 80 won't match 8080 and likewise? Should I make it a C program instead? Or is there already a small utility like this?

Comment: Using SIGKILL is usually a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/690631/347411). Any reason why you don't want the process to clean up after itself?

Comment: Stopping the server as `mvn jetty:stop` could fail if the instance has `OutOfMemoryError`. When I restart java servlets it happens that the port is not available even at a regular stop such as `mvn jetty:stop`. Sometimes the process can get `OutOfMemoryError` and won't free the TCP port at a regular shutdown such as `mvn jetty:stop`.

Comment: Still, `mvn jetty:stop` is not the same as sending SIGTERM, and the jvm should still be able to process SIGTERM even though its application(s) is out of mem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[fuser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/fuser.1.html) can do that:

```
sudo fuser -KILL -k -n tcp 8088
```

Answer (score 3):

A command can be formulated like this:

```
netstat -lpn | grep ":1234\b" | awk '{sub(/\/.*/, "", $NF); print $NF}' | xargs -i kill -kill {}
```

Explanation:

1. `netstat -ltpn`

   - This lists the listening ports (`l`) on TCP (`t`) and their programs (`p`) without resolving port numbers to names (`n`).
2. `grep ":1234\b"`

   - This searches for `:1234` followed by a boundary (`\b`), indicating the end of the word (or number, in our case). This makes sure that we don't catch `:12345` for example.
3. `awk '{sub(/\/.*/, "", $NF); print $NF}'`

   - This

     - substitutes `sub(/regex/,"replacewith", #fieldnumber)`
     - this regex `\/.*`
     - with nothing `""`
     - in the field `$NF`, which means the last field (i.e. the field that contains `PID/program`)
     - then prints it `print $NF`.

     The regex `\/.*` matches a literal `/` and everything after it, and then we're replacing it with nothing, essentially deleting it, so we're left with only the PID number in that field.
4. `xargs -i kill -kill {}`

   - `xargs -i` is a program that allows you to make the output of the previous command act as the input to another command. Our command is `kill -kill {}` where `{}` indicates "the output from the previous command in the pipeline", which is our PID number.

**Note:** this whole command might be a little bit dangerous because you might accidentally kill something you didn't want to. It could use with a little bit more sanitization. Just make sure you get the correct port number when using it.

If you want to make this into a function, you can add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
killatport(){
    netstat -lpn | grep ":$1\b" | awk '{sub(/\/.*/, "", $NF); print $NF}' | xargs -i kill -kill {}
}
```

Save and apply the changes using `source ~/.bashrc`. Now, you can use the function like this:

```
killatport 8088
```