# Error on apache2 installation

Tags: 20.04, apache2

I am trying to install apache on my new Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

But I get the following error:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
 using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And the output in text:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache-htcacheclean.service → /lib/systemd/system/apache-htcacheclean.service.
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-30 20:23:49 CET; 17ms ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 31745 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31745]: Action 'start' failed.
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31745]: The Apache error log may have more information.
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-6ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not seem to be in the error you describe.
More probably it is caused by the fact, that port 80 is already in use.

```
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
dic 30 20:23:49 xxx-laptop apachectl[31755]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

Check what uses the port and stop it, that should help.

To check what uses the port, you can use `netstat -tulpn | grep 80`

Example output -

```
root@server:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      761/apache2
```

So in my case, the port is taken by apache.

Comment: I get for port 80: `tcp     0     0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN` and `tcp6     0     0 :::80     :::*     LISTEN`.

Comment: I think it is normal that tcp will be listening on port 80, isn't it??

Comment: You should get result, that also provide name of the process using it. Like this -


root@server:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      761/apache2

Comment: Also, if netstat is not showing the process, you might try this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/423756/oneliner-command-to-use-kill-given-tcp-port-number-instead-of-pid